# Nginx on ubuntu 12.04 keep refusing OPTIONS requests

Tags: nginx, cors

I am trying do do cross domain Ajax calls inside an angular service in an ionic application tested in chrome. 
I am trying to do a `POST` on my API and nginx keep refusing my `OPTIONS`.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wss.dev:8080/api/checkin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

I tried different configuration but none of seems to work.

My conf is a follow :

```
server {
   listen                *:8080;

 server_name           wss.dev www.wss.dev;
 client_max_body_size 200m;

 index  index.html index.htm index.php;

 access_log            /var/log/nginx/wss.dev.access.log;
 error_log             /var/log/nginx/wss.dev.error.log;
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE' ;
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With,XMLHttpRequest';

 location ~ .php$ {

     root  /var/www/public;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php /index.php$is_args$args$is_args$args;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
     fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV dev;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     include fastcgi_params;
 }
 location / {

     root  /var/www/public;
     try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php$is_args$args;
 }
 sendfile off;
}
```

I tried like in this example :
https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration.html

I tried different configurations and I tried to change the my alls are made in angular but nothing works...

Comment: Question also asked on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760232/nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04-keep-refusing-options-requests-done-from-ionic-app-tested

Comment: `Question also asked on stackoverflow` why?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a server problem or a code problem

Answer (score 2):

Getting no response might be caused by configuration similar to this:

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|DELETE)$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

Which means that nginx will close the connection without a proper response, that's why this is so difficult to debug.

**Search your configuration for the 444 return code.** If you find something like the above, just add `OPTIONS` to the list).

Comment: I have no configuration for 444. You have my full vhost configurations in the question. In which conf file should I look for it? There is no occurences of it in any of my conf files in `/etc/nginx` nor in any subdrectories.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to post from a local dev box? [Chrome has a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/4965912) that does not support `localhost` for CORS requests, change it to something like "mylocalbox.dev" and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still getting the same error. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wss-pulse.dev:8080/api/checkin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wss-mobile.org:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.`

Comment: Try doing it explicitly in the nginx config; change your first add_header line to this:  ``add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://wss-mobile.org:3000'``

Comment: Tried that too this morning but I've got the exact same error. Actually it was one of the first things I tried  but I tried again just in case.

Comment: I tried with firefox and safari to see of it was chrome's fault but I add the same problem with them too. (using localhost, 127.0.0.1 and hostname setted in /etc/hosts).

Comment: If you do a ``curl -I  http://wss-pulse.dev:8080/api/checkin"`` you should be getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. If you are getting that, it's probably a problem with your script.

Comment: Still getting 405 errors : `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 14:38:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=e1q1v7t7c5stbvhckmqv0cjro4; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache`

Comment: Oops, add_header won't get added on that error. What else is on that server that you can try? Can you do a ``curl -I http http://wss-pulse.dev:8080/somejpeghere.jpg``?  Basically you want to see that header in the response. If you're not getting it, restart nginx.

Comment: I tried : `curl -I  http://wss-pulse.dev/img/ajax.gif` and it is working, my cors header are setted correctly : `[too long for the comments section...]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With,XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Ranges: bytes`

Comment: Actually I can even do POST in curl or a rest client like postman and it is working. It just refuse my OPTIONS ...